# Firefox stopped displaying XML files. How to fix?

Tags: firefox, xml

I've been happily using `Firefox version 56` for a long time to view XML tree by just clicking the `.xml` file. But now, suddenly, Firefox switched to only display the concatenation of the text content of XML elements.

As an example, if the XML document has :

```
<rootElt>
   <myElt>Some text.</myElt>
   <otherElt>Another text.</otherElt>
</rootElt>
```

Instead of showing that document tree, Firefox only shows:

```
Some text.Another text.
```

I haven't changed any configurations and It happened overnight with no apparent reason. Other browsers, including Firefox Dev Edition don't show this problem.

I am not interested in updating version 56 because that would break my add-ons. Is there any fix for this issue on this version?

Comment: You probably have an extension that is causing FF to only display the text nodes.  Try disabling ALL you extensions and the opening an XML file.

Comment: @fpmurphy1 Yep! That was it.  In my case, I had the VTZilla 2.1.1 extension installed.  After disabling it, XML files are displayed normally.  Curiously, it worked well before, but all of a sudden it began to cause the problem.  Thanks!

Comment: I realized that the LastPass, React DevTools and Redux DevTools Add-ons also breaks the pretty XML formatting

Comment: Same question asked on Stack Overflow: [Why XML file is not rendered properly in Firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10649253/why-xml-file-is-not-rendered-properly-in-firefox)

Comment: In my case it was Tampermonkey – see https://github.com/Tampermonkey/tampermonkey/issues/1480 and https://github.com/Tampermonkey/tampermonkey/issues/1609. Pity, the one add-on I really use.

Answer (score 2):

This will actually be fixed in Firefox 74. See:
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1605657

There is no need to add a Doctype. XSD would be more appropriate for XML anyway.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this post](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1193967), you have to add the `<Doctype>` tag to your XML document.

As a workaround, you can also right-click the page and select *View Page Source*.

Comment: Can you be more specific about *which* `<Doctype>` to add?